# stored procedure to check whether all year exist in table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I need to create a stored procedure which can check whether year exist or not between a given start and end year and return those years which exist. for example if I provide 2000 as start year and 2005 end year then it should return those years which exist in table. I have tried the following code but it is not working.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckExistenceforyear] 

    @StYear int  = 0, 
    @EdYear int = 0,
    @SubStationID int = 0,
    @YrString varchar(255) = null Output
AS
BEGIN   
SET NOCOUNT ON;    

    Declare @TempValue varchar(4)
    if @StYear <= @EdYear
    while @StYear <= @EdYear
    Begin
    if (select Count(Sub.Year) from table sub where Sub.Year=@StYear and Sub.SubStationID = @SubStationID) > 0
            Begin

            select  @TempValue=Sub.Year from table as sub where Sub.Year=@StYear and Sub.SubStationID = @SubStationID
                set @YrString = @YrString + @TempValue  
            End
            set @StYear = @StYear +1  
        End
    Else
        return -1 

    select @YrString    
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can USE simple query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR FROM TABLE WHERE YEAR BETWEEN STARTYEAR AND ENDYEAR.
```

The [**BETWEEN**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) operator is used in a WHERE clause to select a range of data between two values.